# How to run OnSelectedIndexChanged for a particular DataGridItem?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagrid

I have made a DataGrid with a template that contains a radiobutton list and dropdownlist.
On change of index of radiobutton list, the dropdownlist gets populated with values. My OnSelectedIndexChanged method code is:

```
Protected Sub rbtnLstOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
                Dim rbLst As RadioButtonList
        Dim DBAccess As New DBAccess
        Dim check As Integer
        Dim strQuery As String
        Dim ddl As String

        Dim newval As String

        For Each dgItem As DataGridItem In dgQuestions.Items

            rbLst = CType(dgItem.FindControl("rbtnLstOptions"), RadioButtonList)
            ddl = CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
            newval = CType(dgItem.FindControl("rbtnLstOptions"), RadioButtonList).SelectedValue


            If (rbLst.SelectedValue.ToString <> "" And ddl = "") Or (rbLst.SelectedValue.ToString <> "" And rbLst.SelectedValue <> Me.PreviousSelectedValue) Then
                check = rbLst.SelectedItem.Value
                strQuery = "Select SNo,Participant from Participants where Role=" & check
                dsRoles = DBAccess.RunQueryReturnDataset(strQuery)
                CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).DataTextField = "Participant"
                CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).DataValueField = "SNo"
                CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).DataSource = dsRoles
                CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).DataBind()
                CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).Visible = True
                'Me.PreviousSelectedValue = rbLst.SelectedValue
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

When this code is run, all the datagrid items are traversed and according to the conditions given, it is populated with the values. I want that this method to execute only when a particular datagrid item radiobutton index is changed and not for all the datagrid items.

Answer (score 0):

Use SELECT CASE to check its index?

```
Protected Sub rbtnLstOptions_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Select Case rbtnLstOptions.SelectedIndex    'ADD THIS
        Case 1,3,5 'This are the radio button indices where you only want an action to take effect
             Dim rbLst As RadioButtonList
             Dim DBAccess As New DBAccess
             Dim check As Integer
             Dim strQuery As String
             Dim ddl As String

             Dim newval As String

             For Each dgItem As DataGridItem In dgQuestions.Items

                 rbLst = CType(dgItem.FindControl("rbtnLstOptions"), RadioButtonList)
                 ddl = CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
                 newval = CType(dgItem.FindControl("rbtnLstOptions"), RadioButtonList).SelectedValue


                 If (rbLst.SelectedValue.ToString <> "" And ddl = "") Or (rbLst.SelectedValue.ToString <> "" And rbLst.SelectedValue <> Me.PreviousSelectedValue) Then
                     check = rbLst.SelectedItem.Value
                     strQuery = "Select SNo,Participant from Participants where Role=" & check
                     dsRoles = DBAccess.RunQueryReturnDataset(strQuery)
                     CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).DataTextField = "Participant"
                     CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).DataValueField = "SNo"
                     CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).DataSource = dsRoles
                     CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).DataBind()
                     CType(dgItem.FindControl("ddlMembers"), DropDownList).Visible = True
                     'Me.PreviousSelectedValue = rbLst.SelectedValue
                 End If
             Next
        Case Else
            'Do something here or just remove this
    End Select
End Sub
```